# Uploading image from discord.js bot to my website

Tags: html, node.js, file-upload, discord.js

I want to use message.attachments to get images from that and upload those to my website (not on localhost). How would i do that?

I already have a working upload form on my website, but how would i do it from a discord.js bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url), each attachment has a URL property. You can use this to get the image and upload it.

Example code:

```js
const URLsToFetch = [];
const attachments = message.attachments.array();
for(let i = 0;i<attachments.length;++i){
  URLsToFetch.push(attachments[i].url);
}
```

This would get all the attachment URLs, which you can use `http`, `request`, or some other similar module to download it and then write it to wherever you put your uploads:

```js
const http = require("http");
const https = require("https");
const {URL} = require("url");
const fs = require("fs");
for(let url of URLsToFetch){
  const uri = new URL(url);
  const protocol = uri.protocol;
  let proto = http;
  if(protocol === "https:"){
    proto = https;
  }
  proto.get(uri,response=>{
    const chunks = [];
    response.on("data",chunk={
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    response.on("end",()=>{
      const file = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      fs.writeFile("path/to/filename",file,err=>{
        if(err){throw err} // error
        // successfully wrote file
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: so i now have the file but how do i upload it to my website?

Comment: It depends on how your website works. This code basically downloads the images from discord and puts it somewhere in your filesystem. You would need to have something to read these files and use them on your website.

Comment: is it possible to make a kind of form that i send to the page? because i currently use a from with the file input type and use php to put it in my images folder with a unique id

Comment: i meant form instead of from

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, you might want to ask another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: i meant for instead of with